# bad class : class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0 Maven Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors

Bad Class Error : My system doesn't have Java 11 it is still pointing to Java 8 ( at Environment Variable, Eclipse Build Path, Eclipse Java Compiler Level) still there is an compilation error class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0.

Recently, there is an upgrade of chrome to 122 version, later on we had to update selenium to 4.17.0 & web driver to 5.6.3 to make it compatible with chrome 122 version.

Error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: testrunners/MyTestRunner has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

[image: Error]
POM.xml :

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HybridFramework1</groupId>
    <artifactId>HybridFramework1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
 
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.9.0</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
 
    </properties>
 
    <dependencies>
 
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.18.1</version>
</dependency>
 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.3</version>
</dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        <!--    <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
 
 
 
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
        <plugins>
 
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/ParallelRun.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
 
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version> <executions> <execution> <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals> <configuration>
            UNCOMMENT - To add any exclusions if required <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IT*.java</exclude> </excludes> <includes> UNCOMMENT
            BELOW LINE
                - To execute feature files with a single runner
            <include>**/MyTestRunner.java</include>
                UNCOMMENT BELOW LINE -
            To execute feature files with multiple runners
            <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                </includes> UNCOMMENT BELOW
            3 LINES - To execute using parallel or combination
                option
            <parallel>methods</parallel> <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                UNCOMMENT BELOW
            3 LINES - To execute using forking or combination option
            <forkCount>2</forkCount> <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports_${surefire.forkNumber}</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
 
 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA8TB.png
```

Comment: What is the exact message you receive, and what are you doing when you get it? Maybe one of those dependencies requires Java 11.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal(!) reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the full error message in your question. It is up to you to find out which class is compiled with Java 11 instead of Java 8. Is it a dependency or your code?

Comment: Upgrade your plugins version using ancient old ones (surefire 2.22.2? currently 3.1.5) also the error tells you are using dependency which requires JDK11+ instead of JDK 8... also the dependency should be upgraded poi is at version 5+ also cucumber versions are in the meatime at 7+ (7.15.0)...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have tried updating as per your recommendation & it resulted in different error altogether

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: testrunners/MyTestRunner has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated latest POM.xml & the error message in detail. Can you help me to spot the error

Answer (score 0):

It is versioning error, because of Java 8, if there is no option to upgrade - downgrade other dependencies; btw even if your system has 'hardcoded' jre8 in the path that you can not update it even for your user only, you still can download needed JDK from Oracle and choose it in your IDE setting for your project